# Measures of non-abelian-ness

Tags: finite-groups, gr.group-theory, pr.probability, reference-request

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian group of $n$ elements.
I would like a measure that intuitively captures the
extent to which $G$ is non-commutative.
One easy measure is a count of the non-commutative products.
For example, for $S_3$, 9 products are non-commutative,
or, 18 of the 36 entries in the multiplication table indicate
non-commutivity
(in the table, $r$=rotation; $f$=flip):

          
[image: S3Table]

So one might say $S_3$ is 50% non-abelian.

Another idea is to determine the fewest element identifications
needed to make the group abelian.  If one identifies
the elements $r$ and $r^2$ above, and calls the resulting merged element $a$,
then I believe $S_3$ is reduced to the abelian $C_2$:

          
[image: S3RedC2]

So one might say $S_3$ is one element identification away from being abelian.

My question is:

> Is there some standard, accepted measure 
>   of how far a group is from being abelian?

Ideally such a measure would not be restricted to finite groups.  Thanks
for pointers!

Comment: A pair of standard notions in this general context is the commutator subgroup and the abelianization (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup ) On could then compare the respective cardinalities of the groups and these (or one of these suffices) derived groups. It am, however, not sure if this really goes in the direction you envision

Comment: The nilpotency class and the derived length are 'measures of non-abelianness' in a sense.  You could also look at complex character degrees: a finite group is abelian if and only if all its irreducible characters are of degree 1.  For finitely generated infinite groups, you could ask how far a Cayley graph is from having a 'Euclidean' metric, which takes you into distortion theory.  I don't think there is one standard measure that suits all purposes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Derived_series

Comment: @Colin: In fact, the nilpotence class is not such a good measure for non-Abelianness in some senses. Consider a large dihedral $2$-group of order $2^{n+1}$. It has an Abelian (normal) subgroup of index $2,$ but has nilpotence class $n$.

Comment: For general algebras, there is a notion of Abelian which corresponds to the usual notion in the case of groups and rings.  For finite algebras, this has a directly calculable and measurable impact on the congruences of an algebra.  The concept has also been used in decidability issues for certain classes of varieties.  If you are interested, Joseph, I'll dig around in my notes and post a more detailed answer later.  I doubt though that you will get some notion of probability out of it.  Gerhard "Amazed About Remembering This Stuff" Paseman, 2013.03.25

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke $E^\infty$-algebra are abelian.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Of course, one might say that both $Z(G)$ and $[G,G]$, in a sense, "measure" the non-commutativity of $G$. But they are not very good "quantitative" measures.

I think what you are aiming at is a notion introduced by Turán and Erdős (*Some problems of a statistical group theory IV*, Acta Math. Acad. of Sci. Hung. **19** (1968), 413-435), the "probability that two elements of $G$ commute":
$$P(G) = \frac{\left|\{ (x,y)\in G\times G\mid
  xy=yx\}\right|}{|G|^2}.$$
In fact, $P(G) = k/|G|$, where $k$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. Gustafson proved that if $G$ is nonabelian then $P(G)\leq 5/8$, and extended the notion to compact groups using Haar measure (W. Gustafson, *What is the probability that two group elements commute?* American Math. Monthly **80** (1973) 1031-1034). MacHale proved that certain values cannot occur: if $P(G)\gt \frac{1}{2}$, then $P(G) = \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2s+1}$; and $P(G)$ cannot satisfy $\frac{7}{16} \lt P(G) \lt \frac{1}{2}$. Joseph proved that if $G$ is not commutative and $p$ is the smallest prime that divides $|G|$, then $P(G)\leq \frac{p^2+p-1}{p^3}$ (K.S. Joseph, *Commutativity in non-abelian groups*, PhD thesis, 1969, UCLA). There's been some other work on this.

In the case of $S_3$. $|G|=6$, and the set of pairs $(x,y)$ with $xy=yx$ is, as you note, $18$, so the probability that two elements commutes is precisely your "50% nonabelian".

Your second notion seems to be that of looking at $G/[G,G]$, which is the "largest" quotient of $G$ which is abelian.

**Added:** Since I edited to fix the accent on Erdős, I'll take the opportunity to add some references:

- Desmond MacHale, *How commutative can a non-commutative group be?*, Math. Gazette **58** (1974), 299-202.
- David J. Rusin, *What is the probability that two elements of a finite group commute?*, Pacific J. Math **82** (1979), no. 1, 237-247.
- Robert Guralnick and Geoff Robinson, *On the commuting probability in finite groups*, J. Algebra **300** (2006), no. 2, 509-528, MR 2228209 (2007g:60011); *Addendum*, J. Algebra **319** (2008), no. 4, 1822.

Comment: @Arturo: TheTurán-Erdős model is perfect--Thanks so much!  Fascinating that certain values of $P(G)$ cannot occur.

Comment: Links:  [MacHale](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615961) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=466317)); [Rusin](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102785075) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=549847)); [Guralnick and Robinson](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305007179) and [erratum](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869307003705) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2228209)).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first sentence of this answer? Why are $Z(G)$ and $[G,G]$ not good quantitative measures?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: The size of the groups doesn’t give you a good gauge of how likely two elements are to commute. You could have a very “nonabelian” group with very few commutators, quantitatively speaking, or a group with very small center but where lots and lots of things commute with one another.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin With regard to the very last point you just made, is it true that for any small $\epsilon, \delta>0$ we can find a group $G$ with $P(G) > 1 - \epsilon$ but $\frac{|Z(G)|}{|G|} < \delta$? In other words, "small centre" but "lots and lots of things commute". Is there a concrete example of this?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: $P(G)$ cannot exceed $\frac{5}{8}$ in a noncommutative group, *as it says in the answer*. So the answer is obviously “no”, because if you pick $\epsilon$ too small, then $Z(G)=G$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Look: if I tell you I have a group with trivial center, that doesn’t really tell you how likely two elements are to commute. If I tell you I have a group with $G=G’$, that also does not tell you much about how likely two elements are to commute; worse if I tell you “I have a group with commutator subgroup of order $1000$”. That’s why I said that neither the center nor the commutator subgroups are good quantitative measures of how “abelian” a group is. **Six** years ago...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My apologies. Overlooking what was mentioned in the answer was quite foolish of me. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 14):

You may want to look at the commutativity graph of a finite groups (vertices are elements, an edge connects $a$ and $b$ if $ab=ba$. This and similar graphs have been extensively studied. See, for example, [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.4627.pdf) paper and the references there.

Comment: "On commutativity and finiteness in groups," by Oliveira and Sidki.  Thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, as Arturo says, you probably want what is known as the "commuting probability of $G$", cp(G). Bob Guralnick and I proved (among other things) in a Journal of Algebra paper (circa 2006) (without using the classification of finite simple groups) that $cp(G) \to 0$ as $[G:F(G)] \to \infty,$ where $F(G)$ is the largest nilpotent normal subgroup of a finite group $G,$ though sharper results are possible using the classification.

Comment: *On the commutating probability in finite groups*, J. Algebra **300** (2006), no. 2, 509-528, MR 2228209 (2007g:60011); *Addendum*, with sundry references, J. Algebra **319** (2008), no. 4, 1822. Sorry I omitted it from my (brief) list of references.

Comment: That should be *commuting probability*, not "commutating probability". Sorry.


Comment: @Arturo: Neither apology necessary! Not being able to edit comments is sometimes a pain.

Answer (score 10):

For certain applications, the abelian-ness of a group is inversely proportional to the *quasirandom-ness* of a group. The latter notion is more obscure, so this observation might not be a help at first. On the other hand quasirandom-ness *can* be measured quantitatively in a number of basically equivalent ways.

This is all laid out very beautifully in the paper *Quasirandom groups* by Tim Gowers. This is the first paper where the notion of a quasirandom group rears its head, and Gowers gives five equivalent definitions. Perhaps the most accessible is this: a group is *$c$-quasirandom* if the smallest dimension of a non-trivial irreducible representation is at least $c$. Obviously abelian groups are 1-quasirandom, but not 2-quasirandom; indeed, the same is true of all non-perfect groups.

On the other hand Gowers makes this remark about the family of groups $PSL_2(q)$:

> ...the
>   order of $PSL_2(q)$ is $q(q^2 − 1)/2$, so the lowest dimension of a non-trivial representation is
>   proportional to the cube root of the order of the group. This tells us that, in a certain
>   sense, $PSL_2(q)$ is very far from being abelian.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that the following will be useful, however...

Similarly to the answer of Mark Sapir let us consider the "anti-commutativity" graph  (an edge connects $a$ and $b$ if $ab\ne ba$). Of course, it is not connected, and the number of its connected components  can be taken as some measure of non-abelian-ness. E.g., this measure equals 2 (minimal value) for $S_n (n\ge 5)$.

Addendum: Morfeover, every simple group has the measure 2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the same notions of "non-abelianness" also apply to semigroups. Should the notions somehow take into account the added structure a group has?

Comment: The above "answer" should probably be a comment elsewhere.  In any case, it's worth noting that while $Pr(G) \leq 5/8$ when $G$ is a group (and there are various other values below $5/8$ that are not the commuting probability for any group $G$) the commuting probability of a semigroup can be anything.  This is proved <a href="http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~vadim/ps.pdf">here</a>.

Comment: The link is broken due to the HTML content; should be www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~vadim/ps.pdf