# Why can't a nonabelian group be 75% abelian?

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, finite-groups, topological-groups

This question asks for intuition, not a proof.
An earlier question,
[Measures of non-abelian-ness](https://mathoverflow.net/q/125501/6094)
was thoroughly answered by Arturo Magidin.
A paper by Gustafson<sup>1</sup>
proves that, for a nonabelian group,
the probability that two randomly selected
elements commute is at most $5/8$, a tight bound<sup>2</sup>
that also holds for a class of infinite topological groups.
One might say that a nonabelian group cannot be more than 62.5% abelian.

My question is:

> ***Q***. Is there some intuitive reason that a nonabelian
>   group cannot be "nearly completely abelian" in the sense that
>   the probability that two element commute approaches $1$?
>   Why, intuitively, is there an upper bound less than $1$?

Gustafson's proof uses the conjugacy class equation,
and bounds on the terms of this equation.
I am seeking an underlying logic that can be conveyed without these calculations.

(Incidentally, there is no universal lowerbound on the probability, so
groups can be nearly completely nonabelian.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Gustafson, W. H.
"What is the probability that two group elements commute?"
*American Mathematical Monthly* (1973): 1031-1034.
([Jstor link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318778?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).)

<sup>2</sup>"The reader may verify this bound is sharp,
by examining the nonabelian
[groups of order $8$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_8)":
The dihedral group $D_8$,
and the quaternion group $Q_8$.

Comment: There are lots of papers in the literature on this topic, including one by Bob Guralnick and myself. I suppose that one answer to your general question (at least for finite groups), an element $x$ which commutes with more than half the elements of the group $G$ has to be central, using Lagrange's Theorem. So once the probability that a single element $x$ commutes with other group elements gets above 1/2, it has to be 1.

Comment: If you combine Geoff's comment with the fact that the index of the center cannot be smaller than $4$ ($G/Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic), then you get exactly the bound $\frac{5}{8}$: The central elements commute with all other elements, the non-central elements with at most half the elements. At most a quarter of the elements are central, so the probability to commute is bounded by $\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1 + \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{8}$. So the intuition is a single element cannot commute with too many other elements without being central *and* the center itself cannot be too big.

Comment: Thank you, GeoffRobinson and @j.p.! Together your comments provide a lucid logic, just what I sought.

Comment: You should post this as a proper answer.

Comment: @j.p.: Notice that the two facts are interrelated. If we had $[G:Z(G)] < 4$, then every element $x \in G \backslash Z(G)$ would commute with at least $2|Z(G)|$ elements, so with more than $\frac{|G|}{2}$ elements, a contradiction.

Comment: On the other hand, note that the probability that two *semigroup* elements commute can be any rational number, as shown by Givens and by Ponomarenko and Selinski (Givens, B. *The probability that two semigroup elements commute can be almost anything*, College Math J. **39** (5), 399-400, 2008; and also [the paper by Michelle Soule](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/college.math.j.45.2.136)).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin's reference:  [Givens - The probability that two semigroup elements commute can be almost anything](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27646688).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

(In response to suggestion of Johannes Hahn): As indicated in my comment, and developed further in j.p.'s comment, a fairly intuitive "explanation" is provided by the fact that Lagrange's Theorem tells us that an element $x$ of a finite group $G$ is already central in $G$ once it commutes with more than half the elements of $G$ (since $C_{G}(x)$ is a subgroup of $G$). In other words, once the probability that $x$ commutes with elements of $G$ gets above $\frac{1}{2}$, it has to be $1$.

Also, as I mentioned, there are many papers on this topic in the literature. At the other extreme to the question, in one paper, Bob Guralnick and I proved that the probability that two elements of  a finite group $G$ commute tends to $0$ as $[G:F(G)] \to \infty$, where $F(G)$ is the largest nilpotent normal subgroup
of $G$.

Later note: These arguments work not just with finite groups, but also whenever a group  $G$ admits a measure $\mu$  which is invariant under right (or left if preferred)  translation, making $
(G,\mu)$ a probability space. For then it is still true that if the probability that $x$ commutes with a group element gets above $\frac{1}{2}$, we must have $C_{G}(x) = G$, for otherwise $\mu(C_{G}(x)) \leq \frac{1}{2}$, as the $[G:C_{G}(x)]$ right cosets of $C_{G}(x)$ all have equal measure. Similarly, we have $[G:Z(G)] \ge 4$ if $G$ is non-Abelian, since otherwise $\mu(\langle x \rangle Z(G) ) > \frac{1}{2}$ for $x \in G \backslash Z(G)$.

Comment: Guralnick, Robert M., and Geoffrey R. Robinson. "On the commuting probability in finite groups." *Journal of Algebra* 300, no. 2 (2006): 509-528. ([Journal link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305007179).)

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph, there is an even more striking theorem due to Neumann: the commuting probability tends to zero as the index of the largest $2$-step nilpotent normal subgroup tends to infinity ("Two combinatorial problems in group theory". Bull London Math Soc (1989) 21(5):456-458. doi:10.1112/blms/21.5.456).

Comment: @SeanEberhard's reference:  [Neumann - Two combinatorial problems in group theory](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/21.5.456) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1005821)).